# MongoDB storing and querying child objects

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I've two different object with same father. I want to store them in the same collection, but I want to be able to retrieve each object separately.
for example if these are my objects:
[image]

I want to retrieve all of FirstChild objects without retrieving any SecondChild Object.

Is there any way other than adding a type field to the father object, to retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming first child and second child are different types stored in different fields of the father object (father is a composition of first and second child)

```
datastore.find(FatherObject.class).retrievedFields(false,"secondChildField")
```

will get everything except secondChildField or

```
datastore.find(FatherObject.class).retrievedFields(true,"firstChildField")
```

will bring only firstChildField.

Comment: Thanks, It's actually a good solution:)
but the there's more than one field difference between two classes, so a better solution would be passing array of field names which you get from `FirstChild.class.getDeclaredFields()`!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your query, pass in the class reference of the type you want:  `datastore.createQuery(SecondChild.class)`.  Morphia, by default, tracks the class type of the document so it can filter by that type.

Comment: it works only if you store the object type in DB. I didn't wanted to do that at that time! didn't find a way to do so!:(